# Java return symmetric pairs from a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

If I have a 2D array:

```
input[][] = { {"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"B", "A"}, {"C", "E"} }
```

I want an algorithm that returns

```
{("A", "B")} or {("B", "A")}
```

I know there's a solution using HashMap but I want to solve this without. It doesn't need to be the most efficient solution. I want to implement it in O(n log n) time so I don't want to use HashMap. I was thinking of sorting the input array and comparing the elements but I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: A solution using `HashMap` could be `O(n)`.  Don't dismiss that ...

Comment: Are arrays guaranteed to be unique? ie Could input be `{ {"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"A", "B"}, {"C", "E"} }` (`{"A", "B"}` appears twice)?

Answer (score 0):

### Brute force

There’s the brute force approach: For each pair see if the reverse of it is also there. So when you have (A, B), see if you can find (B, A) (which in your example you can). When next you have (C, D), see if you can find (D, C) (this time you cannot). Use nested loops. In the outer loop iterate through the pairs. In the inner loop again iterate through the pairs. If the pair from the inner loop is the reverse of the one from the outer loop, print both pairs.

The approach has time complexity O(n ^ 2) (possibly obvious).

### More efficient: sort the pairs first

Sorting the pairs before you begin will allow you to use binary search for the reverse pair. Sort by first member, then by second member. In your example the sorted order will be

```
(A, B), (B, A), (C, D), (C, E)
```

Again iterate over the pairs. When you got (A, B), use binary search for finding (B, A). When you got (C, D), search for (D, C). I should come after (C, E) in the sorted order, and since there is nothing there, the pair cannot be found.

This latter approach should have time complexity O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

By HashSet

```
static String[] findSymmetricPairByHashSet(String[][] input) {
    record Entry(String a, String b) {}
    Set<Entry> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String[] a : input) {
        Entry p = new Entry(a[1], a[0]);
        if (set.contains(p))
            return new String[] {p.a, p.b};
        set.add(new Entry(a[0], a[1]));
    }
    return null;
}
```

By TreeSet

```
static String[] findSymmetricPairByTreeSet(String[][] input) {
    Set<String[]> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);
    for (String[] a : input) {
        if (set.contains(a))
            return a;
        set.add(new String[] {a[1], a[0]});
    }
    return null;
}
```

By Sort

```
static String[] findSymmetricPairBySort(String[][] input) {
    Arrays.sort(input, Arrays::compare);
    for (String[] a : input)
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(input, new String[] {a[1], a[0]},
            Arrays::compare) >= 0)
            return a;
    return null;
}
```

test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[][] input = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"B", "A"}, {"C", "E"}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findSymmetricPairByHashSet(input)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findSymmetricPairByTreeSet(input)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findSymmetricPairBySort(input)));
}
```

output:

```
[A, B]
[B, A]
[A, B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that seems to work. It doesn't require any sorting.

```
String[][] input = { {"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"B", "A"}, {"C", "E"} };
```

- first, copy concatenated array items to a set.
- then iterate thru the array, doing a reverse concatenation and see if the set contains that string.
- If so, remove both concatenated strings and print the array.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for (String[] arr : input) {
    set.add(arr[0]+arr[1]);
}
for(String[] arr : input) {
    String item1 = arr[1] + arr[0];
    String item2 = arr[0] + arr[1];
    if (set.contains(item1)) {
        set.remove(item1);
        set.remove(item2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

prints

```
[A, B]
```

Alternatives to the above are to forego concatenation and use `Arrays.equals()`, especially for larger sized arrays.  In this case I thought `Arrays.equals()` was overkill.  And in lieu of printing, the array could be saved in another data structure.